# How to display the content in a paragraph vertically using iText Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

How to displaying the paragraph vertically. I have developed this code and I can able to see the paragraph vertically but not completely. Its showing the crossly. You can refer the image above.

```java
private  void stampPdf(InputStream source, OutputStream dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(source), new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    Paragraph header = new Paragraph("Received by ICA on " + getDate())
            .setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA))
            .setFontSize(8);

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        float x = pdfDoc.getPage(i).getPageSize().getLeft();
        float y = pdfDoc.getPage(i).getPageSize().getTop();
        doc.showTextAligned(header.setFontColor(Color.RED), x, y , i,
                TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 90);   
    }
    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem now?

Comment: there is red line right, it should come vertically not crossly. Please assit me on that, you can see in the image attached .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You show the text in this code line:

```
doc.showTextAligned(header.setFontColor(Color.RED), x, y , i,
        TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 90);
```

You attempt to make the orientation vertically by using 90 (degrees) as the angle parameter.

But this `showTextAligned` overload is documented as:

```
/**
 * Convenience method to write a text aligned about the specified point
 *
 * @param p          paragraph of text to be placed to the page. By default it has no leading and is written in single line.
 *                   Set width to write multiline text.
 * @param x          the point about which the text will be aligned and rotated
 * @param y          the point about which the text will be aligned and rotated
 * @param pageNumber the page number to write the text
 * @param textAlign  horizontal alignment about the specified point
 * @param vertAlign  vertical alignment about the specified point
 * @param radAngle   the angle of rotation applied to the text, in radians
 * @return this object
 */
public T showTextAligned(Paragraph p, float x, float y, int pageNumber, TextAlignment textAlign, VerticalAlignment vertAlign, float radAngle)
```

I.e. the angle parameter is expected to be given in radians! Instead of the value `90` you should use `(float) Math.PI / 2f` or `(float) -Math.PI / 2f` (depending on the variant of vertical writing you are after), e.g.:

```
doc.showTextAligned(header.setFontColor(Color.RED), x, y , i,
        TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, (float) Math.PI / 2f);
```

Depending on the variant of vertical writing you are after you might also want to increase `x` a bit to have the writing not just outside the page area.